# Are resale/worth questions OK or not?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I have seen several questions that basically want an opinion on if doing a project is worth their time as far as resale value or what would be the best thing to do while keeping resale value.

I also saw there was another meta question that kind of touched on this but no clear answer.

The fact is that almost everything I do in my home starts with the question - "How can I do this with the highest quality but also get the the most for my money resale-wise?"  My situation is knowing I will leave my house in the next 1-3 years.  Some people may not care about resale value but a LOT of people do when they are scoping out a project.

To get more traffic to the site I personally think that these type of questions are perfect.  They generate a lot of discussion and there really isn't a place on the web that holds this info...

Either way we need to decide if these are cool or not because from meta discussion it seems they are yet they are being deleted as off topic...

Answer (score 6):

No, questions dealing with resale value are not typically considered on topic. Prices, preferences, and market values change far too much too quickly.  These types of questions will be out of date fairly quickly, and so will require constant updating.

While cost and resale value are a part of most projects, it's not the part of the project *we* focus on.  *We* focus on *how* things are done, not whether they make financial sense, or are within a budget, etc.

On a side note, I think you may not understand what makes StackExchange different than a forum.  Here we try to provide awesome answers to peoples questions, not chit-chat about DIY-y stuff.  The point isn't to `generate a lot of discussion`, it's to help people get done what they need to get done.

Comment: In my opinion the site is missing out on a very very large segment on questions that people want to ask.  Maybe it is this "strict" attitude that has kept the # of posts so low.  I also do not think there is anymore variance/dating issues on these questions compared to a normal how to fix something question - code,products,best practices change too.  Also doing a simple search on the topic showed two older posts that both conveyed that resale questions are on topic...

Comment: Also I really like the question/answer layout of SE - I have used stackoverflow since its inception.  However the frustration is that you have a question on how to do something but you cannot discuss the entire scope of the project or your question could get axed - that is where I would take my question to a "forum" and once you go to new site a lot of times you don't go back.  And by the amount of hits this particular site gets I would think this might happen a lot.  There must be something wrong with the DIY scope given the massive network its on with such poor # of visitors.

Comment: And not to rant forever but Tester you are not the typical user the DIY site wants - if they were targeting you they would have a very small target group.  You obviously know your crap and do stuff right.  The typical user would be either - I don't have the $ so get me out of a jam, I don't know who to call help me get started, help me make sure contractor isn't screwing me, how can I get something nice on low budget.  Yes some people love doing DIY projects perfect because they enjoy it - that isn't a high % of people.  DIY infers low $ - a lot of this site is how a pro would do it.

Comment: @DMoore If you think the site is missing a `very very large segment of questions`, start a proposal on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  Obviously I understand that people turn to DIY when money is short, but doing things wrong or hackishly often costs more in the long run.  I can't speak for everybody, but *personally* I try only to give accurate, safe, and correct information.  If that's not what the typical DIY.SE user is looking for, maybe *I'm* in the wrong place.

Comment: I will start a proposal.  I wasn't knocking you at all Tester.  I was trying to convey that you are an answerer (and way out of range of typical person - see this by your rep points and quality of answers).  The site needs more questioners and a person with your experience (or the small population with your experience) won't be asking many questions and if they are they will be very hard to answer.  I really think there is an over reaction to close questions.  We should help new people rephrase if question is way out of whack.  If you go to a site and someone closes your ? you are done with it

Comment: @DMoore People only notice the closed questions.  For every closed question, there are 2 or 3 that have been edited to fit within the scope. For example, [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28521/33) was a blatant "shop for me" question, but it was edited to bring it within the scope of the site.